# how to get href by ng-click a <a> in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

let us say we have a

```
   <a href = "/jsondata" ng-click="myFunction()">Click Here</a>
```

in the angular based application.

```
$scope.myFunction= function(){
        // how to get the href
        $http.get(href).success(function(data) {
        })
}
```

the requirement is to click the  and do a ajax request and get the json data from the server. since I choose to work on the angular, I don't know how to it in angular, since I don't know how to get the href attribute from the  element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<a href = "/jsondata" ng-click="myFunction($event.target.href);$event.preventDefault()">Click Here</a>
```

Js:

```
$scope.myFunction= function(href){
        // how to get the href
        $http.get(href).success(function(data) {
        })
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RUGwR/1/)

Comment: For me **$event.target.href+''** worked ==>
<a href = "/jsondata" ng-click="myFunction(<a href = "/jsondata" ng-click="myFunction($event.target.href+'');$event.preventDefault()">Click Here</a>);$event.preventDefault()">Click Here</a>

Answer (score 2):

I using angularjs 1.5 and $event.target.href didn't work in my app.

I had to do this:

```
<a ng-click="$event.preventDefault();vm.openToolTip($event);" href="J3606">position 36.06</a>
```

js

```
function openToolTip(event){
    var href = event.currentTarget.attributes["href"].nodeValue;
    alert(href);
}
```